# How to make my program asynchronous with asyncio in Python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-3.7

My code is to search the data from the ES database And add some new data in the database . I used to run in a single process, but this is too inefficient, so I want to add asyncio to my code. How can I do it? I removed the URL of my ES data based on security considerations.  is there anyone can help me?

```
import json
import requests
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import asyncio

class Cited:
    def __init__(self):
        self.es = Elasticsearch(
            [''],
        )

    async def get_es_item(self):
        query_body = {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 10000
            ,

            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must":
                        {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "extra.S2PaperId"
                            }
                        }
                    , "must_not":
                        {"exists": {
                            "field": "extra.citations"

                        }}

                }
            }
        }
        items = self.es.search(index='item', body=query_body, doc_type=None, request_timeout=6000)
        items = items['hits']['hits']
        for item in items:
            item_type = item['_type']
            item_id = item['_id']
            S2PaperId = item['_source']['extra']['S2PaperId']
            self.search_ss(item_id=item_id, paperId=S2PaperId, item_type=item_type)

    def search_ss(self, item_id, paperId, item_type):
        headers = {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                          '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
        }

        req = requests.get('https://api.semanticscholar.org/v1/paper/' + paperId, headers=headers, timeout=100)

        # logging.info(req.url)
        if req.status_code == 200:
            req = json.loads(req.text)
            citations = len(req['citations'])
            citationVelocity = req['citationVelocity']
            influentialCitationCount = req['influentialCitationCount']

            self.es.update(index='item', doc_type=item_type, id=item_id,
                           body={'doc': {'extra': {'citations': citations, 'citationVelocity': citationVelocity,
                                                   'influentialCitationCount': influentialCitationCount}}},
                           request_timeout=6000)

            print(item_id, item_type, citations, citationVelocity, influentialCitationCount)
        else:
            print('s2paper 出错了 直接补0' + item_id, item_type)
            self.es.update(index='item', doc_type=item_type, id=item_id,
                           body={'doc': {'extra': {'citations': 0, 'citationVelocity': 0,
                                                   'influentialCitationCount': 0}}},
                           request_timeout=6000)

cited = Cited()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(cited.get_es_item(), cited.get_es_item(), cited.get_es_item(), cited.get_es_item()))
```

Comment: Can you describe in a bit more detail exactly what you would like to do? Do you want the same program to add new data to multiple databases? Or, do you want to run multiple programs in parallel?

Comment: i want to  run multiple programs in parallel  !  The way I used to use a for loop to control a process. Each process's from is a difference of 1000. But later I found that there will still be a bug and the execution speed will be slow. So I want to increase the speed by running multiple programs.

Comment: You are probably best off using the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) standard library module with its [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) class. Asyncio is likely overkill, since `concurrent.futures` already provides convenient primitives for waiting for the tasks to finish.